# How to set unique feature for that particular category product name should be unique using migration laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

There are two table.
Under a category there is a product name.
So, this product name must be unique.?
Like 
cat1 has pro1,pro2
cat2 has pro1,pro3

Table 1 (Migration):

```js
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoryTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('catefory', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('category');
    }
}
```

Tbl2 (Migration )

```html
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('category');
    
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
```

For each category there should be a unique product name. How to define this in laravel migration so that each category there should be a unique products name.?

Answer (score 0):

You can can create your own primary key with group of keys in your table like shown below:-

Tbl2 (Migration )

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->primary(['name', 'category_id']);
            $table->string('name');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('category');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
```

This will ensure each name has a unique product/category.